# How to build TensorFlow Lite native with custom operators?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, bazel, tensorflow-lite

Following this [article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/compiling-a-tensorflow-lite-build-with-custom-operations-cf6330ee30e2). At step 4 when executing command

```
bazel build --cxxopt='--std=c++11' -c opt        \
  --fat_apk_cpu=x86,x86_64,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a   \
  //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite
```

I am getting error. Log output bellow.

```
ERROR: /home/robertas/projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/BUILD:57:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native:native' failed (Exit 1): clang failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/robertas/.cache/bazel/_bazel_robertas/fc35d006e87d344d01f9b09aa9faf335/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3 \
    ANDROID_NDK_API_LEVEL=21 \
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/home/robertas/opt/android/android-ndk-r15c \
    ANDROID_SDK_API_LEVEL=28 \
    ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk \
    PATH=/home/robertas/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk/tools:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/robertas/.local/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages \
    TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=1 \
  external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -gcc-toolchain external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -target x86_64-none-linux-android -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android '-D__ANDROID_API__=21' -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MF bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/_objs/native/builtin_ops_jni.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/_objs/native/builtin_ops_jni.pic.o' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' '-DEIGEN_HAS_TYPE_TRAITS=0' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin -iquote external/flatbuffers -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers -iquote external/gemmlowp -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/gemmlowp -iquote external/androidndk -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/androidndk -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/local_config_sycl -iquote external/arm_neon_2_x86_sse -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/arm_neon_2_x86_sse -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -isystem tensorflow/lite/schema -isystem bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/schema -isystem external/flatbuffers/include -isystem bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/include -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src '--std=c++11' -DFARMHASH_NO_CXX_STRING -Wno-sign-compare -DGEMMLOWP_ALLOW_SLOW_SCALAR_FALLBACK '--sysroot=external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64' -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include -c tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/builtin_ops_jni.cc -o bazel-out/android-x86_64-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/_objs/native/builtin_ops_jni.pic.o)
Execution platform: @bazel_tools//platforms:host_platform
In file included from tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/builtin_ops_jni.cc:17:
./tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/normalize.h:28:10: fatal error: 'absl/strings/str_cat.h' file not found
#include "absl/strings/str_cat.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Target //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite failed to build
```

Environment: Linux, Manjaro Illyria 18.0.4

How this can be fixed?

Comment: Can you take a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22007 and let me know if that helps?

Comment: @the-dagger cloned https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git in top tensorflow directory and then created soft link. No luck. Compilation fails with the same error `fatal error: 'absl/strings/str_cat.h' file not found`

Comment: Can you try following the instructions outlined here : https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/quickstart and add absl to your bazel BUILD script?

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Looks like there are more dependencies than just abseil-cpp. I forked tenserflow repository and did changes based on your article and applied changes from this conversation. This is repository there I am trying to build local tensorflow-lite https://github.com/rsetkus/tensorflow. @the-dagger can you checkout and have a look at it what wrong there?

Comment: @the-dagger first issue has been solved but now I am getting another dependency error `fatal error: 're2/re2.h' file not found`. Seems like now it requires [re2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.h) dependency. From the smartreply BUILD file line `"@com_googlesource_code_re2//:re2",` I assume it prefers remote dependency rather than a local, right? Examples in the WORSPACE didn't work out. How I can resolve this dependency?

Comment: Can you try to manually copy `absl`, `protobuf` and `re2` folders from `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads` to `tensorflow/lite/downloads` and see if that helps? 
I'll try to checkout your repo in the meantime to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @harshithdwivedi but from my previous experience it is obvious to me that is not enough just to copy `absl`, `protobuf` and `re2`. You would need extra Bazel configuration to include as build dependency. Also, I am pretty sure that won't build even including those dependencies because `smartreply` demo doesn't build too.